# Using MySQL 8 as the backend/metadata DB for Superset instead of the default Postgresql DB

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

## *CONTEXT:*

I'm quite new to Kubernetes and Superset.

I'm deploying superset to my k8s cluster using its official helm chart. [https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/helm/superset](https://stackoverflow.com)

By default, helm will create a postgresql pod as the backend DB for storing all the dashboards, config files, tables etc. But I would like to use my own MySQL 8 DB that's easier to be maintained.

## *What I've done*

Now I'm having this issue where it refuses to update the DB for me. Here are some of the things I've tried:

1. I tried to use `configOverrides` to inject my DB along with its details in

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"mysql+mysqldb://{env('DB_USER')}:{env('DB_PASS')}@{env('DB_HOST')}:{env('DB_PORT')}/{env('DB_NAME')}"
```

My understanding of this is to allow superset to automatically connect to the datasource DB and it's not necessarily used for the metadata db connection.

2. I tried to disable postgresql as suggested here [https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/helm/superset/values.yaml#L254](https://stackoverflow.com)
   and I updated the parameters to mine

```
    "postgresql.enabled" = "false"
    "supersetNode.connections.db_host" = "db.host.com"
    "supersetNode.connections.db_port" = "3306"
    "supersetNode.connections.db_user" = "user"
    "supersetNode.connections.db_pass" = "password"
    "supersetNode.connections.db_name" = "superset"
```

But in the values.yaml file it states that this part is for postgresql only. Not sure if I can do it this way for MySQL.

As most of you kuberetes saints expected, none of the above tries worked for me since the `wait-for-postgres` and `wait-for-postgres-redis` init containers are always there. I tried to pass an `exit 0` command to those containers (`"init.initContainers[0].command[2]" = "exit 0"`) but it doesn't really stop k8s from creating the containers. I'm not too sure what to do next.

## *So, my question is:*

- Does superset accept MySQL 8 as its metadata DB? If it does, how to set it up using helm chart?

PS: I understand the easiest way would be to edit the values.yaml file and the template files straightaway, but I would rather keep the files orginal and only make changes if it's shown modifiable in the official chart.

PS: Here are the dependencies I installed

```
apt-get install -y python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential

pip install mysql-connector-python --user --no-input 

pip install mysqlclient --user --no-input  

pip install psycopg2==2.8.5

pip uninstall celery &&\ pip install "celery[redis]" &&
```

Thanks all!